# Vue js: load more data button not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue.js code below I'm trying to add a `Show More` button to my data coming from API so initially it should show 10 data and whenever clicked load more 10 and so on. I tried answer from:

[Load more button in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246481/load-more-button-in-vuejs)

but it's not working since I'm looping over an array it gives me the error below `can't read property of question title`. Is there a way to do it?

```html
<div class="search-askbutton">
            <b-row>
              <div class="search-wrapper">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  v-model="search"
                  placeholder="Search something..."
                  class="fas fa-search"
                />
                </div>

<div class="container vue">
<div v-for="commentIndex in commentsToShow"> 
    <div v-if="commentIndex <= commentsToShow">
        <ul
           class="container-question"
           v-for="(question, index) in filteredList"
           :key="index"
        >
            <div>{{question[commentIndex - 1].questionTitle}} says:</div>
            <hr />
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
   <button @click="commentsToShow += 10">show more</button>
</div>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return { commentsToShow: 10,
        search: '',
        questions: [],}
    },
     computed: {

    filteredList() {
      return this.questions.filter((question) => {
        return (
          question.questionTitle
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          question.owner.username
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          question.questionTitle
            .toUpperCase()
            .includes(this.search.toUpperCase()) ||
          question.owner.username
            .toUpperCase()
            .includes(this.search.toUpperCase())
        );
      });
    },
  },
    mounted: function() {
    questionService.getAllQuestions().then((response) => {
      this.questions = response.data.response;}
}
</script>
```

Comment: please give us the full code

Comment: this is the full code of show more

Comment: where is the ``filteredList`` array though without that I can suggest what might be the issue here

Comment: @ASADALI i updated question, the `questions` array holds all the data coming from API and i used it inside `filteredList` because i used a search bar also so whenever i enter somthing in search bar it will  show it from the `filteredList` and if nothing entered it will show data normally from`filteredList`

Comment: also last can you can make sure the ``questions`` array is defined in data()?

Comment: @ASADALI yes it's defined in data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your subtraction

```
<div>{{question[commentIndex - 1].questionTitle}} says:</div>
```

If commentIndex = 0 then you'll be saying 0-1 = -1 therefore it will not find the -1 index.

You could replace this line

```
<div v-if="commentIndex <= commentsToShow">
```

So that it can run only if the index is greater than 0

```
<div v-if="commentIndex > 0">
```

Comment: well actually in vue, v-for iterate from 1 so the commentIndex start from 1 so the first iteration is [commentIndex - 1] = 0  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range

Answer (score 0):

### 1)

v-for returns what's inside an array, not the array itself.

```
<div>{{question.questionTitle}} says:</div>
```

### 2)

also, you can remove the v-for loop.

note:- your reference question is also uses this way.

```
<div v-for="commentIndex in commentsToShow"> 
 <div v-if="commentIndex <= commentsToShow">
   <ul class="container-question">
    <div>{{filteredList[commentIndex - 1].questionTitle}} says:</div>
   <hr />
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately ican't use direct ` {{filteredList[commentIndex - 1].questionTitle}}` since my response inside an array and i need to loop over to get all data i need

Comment: you can use the spead operator ``this.questions = ...response.data.response;``